# Could any one walk me through this code?

Tags: ruby

I'm easily getting confused with iterations - 
Could anyone walk me through exactly what this code does?
Friends and family are hashes and the language is Ruby.

```
friends.each { |x| puts "#{x}" } 
family.each { |x, y| puts "#{x}: #{y}" }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `friends` is a Hash and not an Array?

Answer (score 4):

```
friends.each { |x| puts "#{x}" } 
family.each { |x, y| puts "#{x}: #{y}" }
```

The first is basically equivalent to:

```
x = [friends.keys[0], friends.values[0]]
puts "#{x}"
x = [friends.keys[1], friends.values[1]]
puts "#{x}"
x = [friends.keys[2], friends.values[2]]
puts "#{x}"
# ...
x = [friends.keys[n], friends.values[n]]
puts "#{x}"
```

The second:

```
x = family.keys[0]
y = family.values[0]
puts "#{x}: #{y}"
x = family.keys[1]
y = family.values[1]
puts "#{x}: #{y}"
x = family.keys[2]
y = family.values[2]
puts "#{x}: #{y}"
# ...
x = family.keys[n]
y = family.values[n]
puts "#{x}: #{y}"
```

Any time you have something like `{ |...| ... }` or `do |...|; ...; end` after a method, you are creating what is called a block. This block is passed to the method, which can `yield` parameters to the block. `Array#each` will call the block with each element; `Hash#each` will pass `[key, value]`.

You could, of course, do something totally different, like so:

```
def test
  yield('oh my')
  yield('i really')
  yield('like blocks')
end
test { |a| puts a }
```

Which outputs

```
oh my
i really
like blocks
```

If you `yield` an array to a block, it can be assigned to multiple or a single parameter.

```
def test
  yield(['oh', 'my'])
  yield(['i', 'really'])
  yield(['like', 'blocks'])
end
test { |a, b| puts "#{a}-#{b}" }
```

Which outputs

```
oh-my
i-really
like-blocks
```

Or, if you only accept a single parameter in the block, it will be passed as an array

```
test { |a| puts a.inspect }
```

Outputs

```
["oh", "my"]
["i", "really"]
["like", "blocks"]
```

So, say `Array#each` doesn't exist and you want to create it yourself. You could do something like

```
class Array
  def each
    i = 0
    while i < length_of_underlying_array
      next_element = get_element(i)
      yield(next_element)
    end
  end
end
```

Or, `Hash#each`

```
class Hash
  def each
    i = 0
    while i < length_of_underlying_hash
      next_key = keys[i]
      next_value = values[i]
      yield([next_key, next_value])
    end
  end
end
```

Another general tip, since Ruby is open source, you can see exactly how [Array#each](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_195/array.c#L1652) and [Hash#each](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_195/hash.c#L199) are implemented in C, which generally matches the plain Ruby code above.

Answer (score 3):

- A hash `{a: => :b, :c => :d}` is cast to an array `[[:a, :b], [:c, :d]]` when `each` is called.
- If the block on `each` takes one variable `x`, then each element of it is passed, which is `[:a, :b]` for the first iteration, `[:c, :d]` for the next.
- If the block on `each` takes two variables `x` and `y`, then the the each element like `[:a, :b]` is matched with the variables. For the first iteration, `x` becomes `:a` and `y` becomes `:b`.